# Extract values from pandas dataframe to make a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I had created pandas dataframe. Now I am trying to extract a certain time range from this pandas dataframe to create a new dataframe and perform some operation. my data looks like this . .

```
timestamp           temp     presure  
1456411800000000    12.90    12
1456412400000000    13.32    45
1456413000000000    9.32     32
1456413600000000    10.3     13
1456414200000000    12.3     55
1456414800000000    12.5     76
1456415400000000    5.4      43
1456416000000000    2.4      42
1456416600000000    7.66     22
1456417200000000    12.3     66
.
.
.
.
.
1456550400000000    32.4    43
```

This is one dataframe. Now I am trying to extract data let say between two timestamps (1456411800000000 and 1456417200000000) and create new dataframe. 
I am trying but unable to get the desired results. I am getting some errors .

> TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex

the code line which I am using to extract this dataframe is

```
test_df = df.between_time('1456411800000000','1456417200000000')
```

I try something like this to convert them to datetime object

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='us')
```

And it was successful, but I am trying to extract the time range from already present dataframe. 
Can someone guide me to extract values from a dataframe and make a new dataframe from it. I am new to pandas. I would be thankful.

the output of df.head(5) is

```
   timestamp            temp     pressure\
0    1456411800000000      12.90    12                      
1    1456412400000000      13.32    45                            
2    1456413000000000      9.32     32                            
3    1456413600000000      10.3     13                            
4    1456414200000000      12.3     55
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if `timestamp` is of `object` (string) dtype:

```
test_df = df.query("'1456411800000000' <= timestamp <= '1456417200000000'")
```

or

```
test_df = df.loc[df['timestamp'].between('1456411800000000', '1456417200000000')]
```

Comment: i got the following error for 1st one 'ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp'.           and this error for the second one.................... TypeError: invalid type comparison . .

Comment: i fetch the data from the mysql database and in mysql i store it in epoch time with microseconds.

Comment: @khan, make sure that `timestamp` column is of integer dtype first

Comment: the type is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.  .How can I convert the type to int dtype and why is it necessary?  thanks for the help.

Comment: @khan, what is the output of `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: for the timestamp it is ............timestamp: datetime64[ns]. and other two columns .....float64

Comment: @khan, can you post an output of `df.head(5)` in your question?

Comment: @khan, i was asking about your original DF. Before you executed `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='us')`

Comment: i added the output of my df.head(5) at the end of my question. .